# How can select similar columns and remove others?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame as below. I would like to change colnames of Data 2 based on first Column of Data 1, and if the colnames of Data 2 is simialr to Data 1$ A , put the name of Dat 1 $ B for colnames of Data 2, otherwise unsimilar columns ignored.

Data 1:

```
   A    B
2-32   AD
3-45   AC
5-44   BC
```

Data 2:

```
  RS     2-32    5-66   5-44  6-11  3-45
rs34       3       5      6     7    5
rs45       4       3      3     4    5
```

Output:

```
  RS     AD   BC   AC
rs34     3    6     5
rs45     4    3     5
```

I have used 'ifelse'  command but I could not remove unsimilar columns.

```
a<- ifelse (colnames(Data2) %in% Data1 $ A, Dat1 $ B , '')
```

Comment: Outputting your example data with `dput` or explicitly including the code which creates it makes it a lot easier for people to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
names(df2)[-1] <- df1[match(names(df2)[-1], df1$A),]$B
df2 <- df2[,!is.na(names(df2))]

#    RS AD BC AC
#1 rs34  3  6  5
#2 rs45  4  3  5
```